# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar y mostrar un Tab de un TabControl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy utilizando un `TabControl` dentro de un formulario diseñado en C#, este `TabControl` tiene dos Tabs y necesito poder ocultar uno y/o mostrarlo dependiendo de un estado que llega como parámetro desde otro formulario. No encuentro una propiedad de tipo `Visible` o en todo caso `Enabled`.

¿Existe alguna forma de poder ocultar un tab dentro de un TabControl o al menos inhabilitarlo?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los tabs de winfoms no tienen propiedad `Visible`, debes eliminarlo, si no recuerdo mal se hace mediante:

```
TabControl.TabPages.Remove(TabPage);
```

**Edit:**

[Aquí un ejemplo en la web de microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa984280(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes ocupar la propiedad parent, donde para ocultar el tabitem le asignas un parent nulo

```
EsteTabItem.Parent = null;
```

Y para mostrar le asignas el tab control en el que se vaya a encontrar

```
EsteTabItem.Parent = TbCtrlGeneral;
```

Answer (score 1):

En principio el control TabControl de Windows Forms no permite mostrar / ocultar una ficha. Lo que puedes hacer es eliminarla aunque perderías los controles de esa ficha.

Una forma de hacerlo sería guardar en un array los controles de tipo TabPage que has marcado como invisibles para poder añadirlos de nuevo cuando los hagas visibles.

Espero que no moleste que escriba el código de un control que hace precisamente esto, desciende de TabControl y mantiene una lista con los controles invisibles para mostrarlos después. El otro array (arrBoolPagesVisible) se utiliza para mantener los índices e insertar los controles en el mismo lugar que estaban al principio.

Pasándole el índice de la ficha que quieres mostrar / ocultar al  método ShowTab de este control, obtendrás el resultado que buscas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bau.Controls.TabControls
{
/// <summary>
///     Control que extiende <see cref="TabControl"/> para permitir ocultar fichas
/// </summary>
public class TabControlExtended : System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
{ // Variables con las páginas
        private List<System.Windows.Forms.TabPage> objColPages = null;
        private bool[] arrBoolPagesVisible;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Inicializa las variables antes de procesar
    /// </summary>  
    private void InitControl()
    { if (objColPages == null)
            { // Inicializa la colección de páginas y elementos visibles
                    objColPages = new List<System.Windows.Forms.TabPage>();
                    arrBoolPagesVisible = new bool[TabPages.Count];
                // Añade las páginas de la ficha a la colección e indica que son visibles
                    for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < TabPages.Count; intIndex++)
                        { // Añade la página
                                objColPages.Add(TabPages[intIndex]);
                            // Indica que es visible
                                arrBoolPagesVisible[intIndex] = true;
                        }
            }
    }   

    /// <summary>
    ///     Muestra una ficha
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowTab(int intTab)
    { ShowHideTab(intTab, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Oculta una ficha
    /// </summary>
    public void HideTab(int intTab)
    { ShowHideTab(intTab, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Muestra / oculta una ficha
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowHideTab(int intTab, bool blnVisible)
    { // Inicializa el control
            InitControl();
        // Oculta la página
            arrBoolPagesVisible[intTab] = blnVisible;
        // Elimina todas las fichas
            TabPages.Clear();
        // Añade únicamente las fichas visibles
            for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < objColPages.Count; intIndex++)
                if (arrBoolPagesVisible[intIndex])
                    TabPages.Add(objColPages[intIndex]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Cuenta el número de fichas visibles
    /// </summary>
    public int CountTabsVisible
    { get
            { int intNumber = 0;

                    // Cuenta el número de páginas visibles
                        if (objColPages != null)
                            for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < arrBoolPagesVisible.Length; intIndex++)
                                if (arrBoolPagesVisible[intIndex])
                                    intNumber++;
                    // Devuelve el número de páginas visibles
                        return intNumber;
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo para retirar y agregar `TabPages` a un `tabControl`:

```
if (this.Editar)
{
    this.tabControlDetalle.TabPages.Add(this.tabPageEdicion);
    this.tabControlDetalle.TabPages.Add(this.tabPageListaPersonas);
}
else
{
    this.tabControlDetalle.TabPages.Remove(this.tabPageEdicion);
    this.tabControlDetalle.TabPages.Remove(this.tabPageListaPersonas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es colocar en `Enable = false` todo lo que tengas dentro de una pestaña, moverlo true y false, sí lo va a ver el usuario final pero no lo va a poder usar.

Answer (score 0):

//Pestañas crear eliminar Array y contador

```
    ArrayList ListaPestaña = new ArrayList();

    int ContarPestaña = 1;

    private void CrearPestaña()

    {
        // Creamos una nueva Pestaña

        TabPage NuevaPestaña = new TabPage("Nombre_Pestaña" + ContarPestaña); // Creamos una nueva pestaña

        ListaPestaña.Add(NuevaPestaña); // cada pestaña creada los añadimos en un arraylist

        tabVentasProd.TabPages.Add(NuevaPestaña); //cargamos la pestaña en el control

        ContarPestaña++; //variable que lleva el control de la cantidad de pestaña creada

        tabVentasProd.SelectedTab = NuevaPestaña; //seleccionamos la pestaña

    }

    private void EliminarPestaña()

    {
        TabPage current_tab = tabVentasProd.SelectedTab;

        ListaPestaña.Remove(current_tab);

        tabVentasProd.TabPages.Remove(current_tab);

        ContarPestaña--;
    }

    //Botones Asignados a la creacion y borrado de pestañas de ventas

    private void BtnNuevaVenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrearPestaña();
    }

    private void BtnEliminarVenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EliminarPestaña();
    }
```

Es indispensable agregar el using System.Collections;